# Что делать, если не отображается ConstraitLayout в AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Я новичок в Android studio и хочу создать свое приложение, но у меня есть проблема. У меня прописан ConstraintLayout и TextView в xml, но не отображается в design. Также я не могу добавлять элементы в design и в Components Tree. В xml у меня написано:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: попробуйте перезагрузить студию с очисткой кэша, так же в студии у вас должно быть предложение рефрешнуть макет сделайте `ctrl+r` по-моему так

Comment: Сделал, но ничего не поменялось. Я чистил кеш разными способами( clean project и invalidate Caches/restart), а рефрешнуть макет у меня почему-то не получается, хотя он сам предлагает. Студия даже не показывает, что процесс начался

Comment: а версия студии у вас какая? просто design в студии порой фризится и виснет, поэтому я бы вам советовал использовать текстовый редактор а не перетаскивать

Comment: У меня версия 4.1.1. Хорошо, буду тогда использовать текстовый редактор, спасибо за ответ